# How to get count children of users

Tags: php, sql

I want to get count of chidren. i try this query but not work
table colums

id,
father_id ,
name

```
select id As parent_id , father_id ,name, count(select * from users WHERE father_id = parent_id) As child
        from users
```

Comment: can you please specify tables with data, so we have clear idea

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score 3):

Use a correlated sub-query to count:

```
select id As parent_id , father_id ,name, (select count(*) from users u2
                                           WHERE u2.father_id = u1.id) As child
from users u1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the table `users` twice. Use table aliases to show what record of the two you are talking of:

```
select 
  id as parent_id, 
  father_id,
  name, 
  (select count(*) from users c where c.father_id = p.id) as children
from users p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with using group_by clause.

select id As parent_id , father_id ,name, count(select * from users WHERE father_id = parent_id) As child
            from users group by parent_id

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this, instead of using *, get the specific field you want to count:

```
    select id As parent_id , father_id ,name, count(select name from users WHERE father_id = parent_id) As child
    from users
```